Как в Fortran записать в файл вещественное число с разделителем в виде запятой?
Как записать в файл с расширением .txt вещественное число с запятой? По умолчанию выводится число с точкой.

В других языках обычно можно установить DecimalSeparator

перед записью превратить число в строку, в строке заменит точку на запятую, сохранить полученную строку в файл.

Ввод/вывод чисел с разделителем запятая можно вызвать установкой параметра DECIMAL='COMMA' в операторе OPEN, см. п. 12.5.6.7 стандарта ISO/IEC DIS 1539-1:2017 (и, вероятно, ISO/IEC 1539-1:2018).
      program decimal
        use iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit

        implicit none

        open(output_unit, decimal='comma')

        print *, 2.3d0

      end program decimal

$ gfortran decimal.f && ./a.out 
   2,2999999999999998     


Спасибо, всё работает!
